# Is there a way to use multiple StringSplitOptions in String.Split()?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to split a string by a delimiter ";" and apply both `StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries` and `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. I tried using an array of StringSplitOptions like

```
// myString already defined elsewhere    
StringSplitOptions[] options = { StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries };
string[] strs = myString.Split(';', options);
```

but this doesn't compile. I know I can remove whitespaces later with Trim(), but would prefer a clean single-statement solution and it seems like you should be able to use multiple (both) options. In the page for the [StringSplitOptions enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0) , it mentions

> If RemoveEmptyEntries and TrimEntries are specified together, then substrings that consist only of white-space characters are also removed from the result.

Neither the rest of the page nor the page for the String.Split() method give any indication of *how* they could be specified together.

I may be missing something simple since I'm fairly new to and self-taught in C#. Excuse me if this post is formatted poorly or is a duplicate question, first post on Stack Overflow. I tried searching for this issue and didn't see any results. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give?

Comment: For flags to work the values have to increase in powers of 2. [The flags attribute has some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0)

Comment: That makes more sense now. Bitwise OR would always give a unique value if the operands are just bit-shifted ones.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

StringSplitOptions enum is marked with [Flags] attribute, and you can combine multiple Flags by `|` operator.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myString = " ; some test     ; here; for;   test   ;   ;   ;";
        string[] strs = myString.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);        
        foreach (var str in strs)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"-{str}-");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-some test-
-here-
-for-
-test-
```

Or

```
StringSplitOptions splitOptions = StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;
string[] strs = myString.Split(';', splitOptions);
```

Comment: Additional clarifications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/5767872

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly! I assumed the bitwise OR of two enum values would be the bitwise OR of their numeric values, but I'm apparently off base. I'll read up on the [Flags] attribute and enums. Thanks again!

Comment: @JSteh No, you're not off base, the bitwise OR of two enum values are exactly the bitwise OR of their numeric values, you're 100% correct in this regard.